# Selectize Not Loading Options With Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express, selectize.js

I am using ExpressJS to build a mangament dashboard for a community I am part of. I currently have a modal that shows up to add new games to a database. The data is fetched remotely but I am having trouble getting the data to show up to select it.

I am able to use to console.log to show the data being retrieved but I am not sure where I am falling short.

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ttitle').selectize({
                create: false,
                valueField: 'appid',
                labelField: 'name',
                searchField: 'name',
                closeAfterSelect: true,
                options: [],
                load: function (query, callback) {
                    if (!query.length) return callback();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: `/games/all?search=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`,
                        type: 'GET',
                        error: function () {
                            callback();
                        },
                        success: function (res) {
                            console.log(res.value)
                            callback(res.value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

While typing in the search box, console shows the following
[image]

HTML - if it matters

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="ttitle">Game Title</label>
   <select name="ttitle" id="ttitle">
      <option></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [`searchField`](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#data_searching) setting takes an array value (not a string), so you need to change it to:

```
searchField: ['name']
```

Otherwise, your setup looks fine.

Comment: hmm, still not sure why the options wont show in the dropdown list. For some reason it seems that the data isn't reaching the part to be rendered, unless I am just missing something.

Comment: @Ryahn unfortunately nothing else in the code you have posted so far jumps out at me. You can try adding `preload: true` to the selectize control settings to see if the data will load initially. That would at least narrow it to some sort of issue with a focus or related event that is preventing your `load` function from executing properly when a query is entered in the field.